# create dictionary from a print output in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

I have a  for loop  inside which  I print each iterations  in the loop   and gives  a output that  is  in the format of  ls-lrt . I would   like to create a dictionary out of this  with key as name of file  and value  as  the timestamp.

```
for attr in sftp.listdir_attr('/abc'):
...     print attr
...
-rwxr-xr-x   1 7202711  7201853      5759 01 Mar 12:49 .nfs0000000615c569f500000004
-rw-r--r--   1 7202711  7201853     62394 26 Sep 2017  1.java
-rwxr-xr-x   1 7202711  7201853      5009 20 Aug 2017  a.sh
-rwxr-xr-x   1 7202711  7201853      2201 15 Oct 2017  adt.sh
drwxr-xr-x   1 7202711  7201853       282 09 Jun 2017  backup
-rwxr-xr-x   1 7202711  7201853      1384 27 Jul 2017  ob.sh
```

If I do  a

```
type(attr)
```

it gives  me

```
<class 'paramiko.sftp_attr.SFTPAttributes'>
```

So the  dict   should  be like (the  date and time  format needs  to be  standardized)

```
{'.nfs0000000615c569f500000004':'01 Mar 12:49',
                                  '1.java':'26 Sep 2017',..............etc}
```

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: is the filename the attr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`SFTPClient.listdir_attr`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir_attr) actually returns a list of [`SFTPAttrributes`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_attr.SFTPAttributes) objects.  It's likely you can access the filename and timestamp of the last modification as `attr.filename` and `attr.st_mtime` (You'll likely need to convert this from a timestamp into a human readable date).  Unfrtunately, these objects seem to be created based on the results of `os.stat`, which don't always return the same thing across operating systems.  You should experiment with all the system types you plan to use this software on.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `listdir_attr()` output also depends on the underlying server implementation. If you already have the printable format you can try splitting the values by `\t` may be use the last splitted value to be your key and second last would be your value. Also you can load the data in pandas dataframe and can directly access the fields you need with column names.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
```

Be sure to import these

```
d = {}
for attr in sftp.listdir_attr('/abc'):
    time_structer = gmtime(attr.st_mtime)
    d[attr.filename] = strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time_structer)
```

Comment: Please feel free to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50140136/edit) your answer, e.g. you can replace `dict` with `d`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do

```
from collections import defaultdict
temp = defaultdict()
for file in sftp.listdir(PATH):
    temp[file].append(sftp.lstat(file)[X]) # where X is the column you want for as your value
```